# What does it mean by "deep-dive chapters", on wich came in the following?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading a book about **Web Development** that suddenly faced this: **deep-dive chapters**.

The entire section came bellow:

> Part 1: Introducing ASP.NET Core This part of the book—which includes
> this chapter—introduces ASP.NET Core. In addition to setting up your
> development  environment and creating your first application, you’ll
> learn about the most important C# features for ASP.NET Core
> development  and how to use the ASP.NET Core development tools. But
> most of Part 1 is given over to the development of a project called
> SportsStore, through which I show you a realistic development process
> from inception to deployment, touching on all the main  features of
> ASP.NET Core and showing how they fit together—something **that can be
> lost in the deep-dive chapters in the rest of the  book**.

So what is the bold section saying? What does it mean by **deep-dive chapters** here?

Comment: Have you looked up the phrase "deep dive"? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Hossein, that is a very trendy word now.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deep%20dive *an exhaustive investigation, study, or analysis of a question or topic*.

Comment: It's fairly transparent imagery. Those chapters ***get right down** to the nitty-gritty details* (so you can gain an ***in-depth** understanding* of the subject).

Comment: One potentially confusing detail: "deep dive" is normally treated as a noun phrase: "After a broad overview, let's take a deep dive into C# class inheritance." The sentence here has put a hyphen between the words and used it as an adjectival phrase to modify "chapters," meaning "chapters that are characterized by being a 'deep dive'."

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't think it's that unusual to use a noun to describe another noun in English.... ice water, government official, health-food aisle, nursery rhyme. Leaving out the hyphen in "deep dive chapters" wouldn't confuse most readers who knew the meaning of "deep dive"; it would have just confused some learners as to which words went together to look up. Because the attributive was properly punctuated, I don't think it should have been that confusing to someone with access to a dictionary.

Comment: @ColleenV Not unusual at all, just worth mentioning as maybe a component of the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deep-dive chapters are ones that **go into a subject in great depth** or **in great detail**.

The writer is saying that this: features of ASP.NET Core and showing how they fit together—

can be lost in those very detailed chapters.

deep dive is a noun; deep-dive x is deep dive used as an adjective.